# How to turn on/off a 5 V, 10 A relay from 5 V, 0.2 mA input signal

Tags: microcontroller, transistors, mosfet, diodes, relay

I am working on a project where I have to switch on/off a 5 V, 10 A relay to turn on/off a 230 VAC LED light using 3.3 V, 0.2 mA of input voltage and current respectively from the microcontroller.

I know that the current supply is not enough to trip the relay. Please provide a solution so that I can provide proper current and voltage to the relay module.

Note: I tried to trip the relays using transistor and MOSFET. Nothing seems to work.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffexSB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The relay coil requires 5 V, 10 A. I have used an IRFZ44N MOSFET and a TIP122 transistor.

Rated coil power is 0.36 W (48 VDC, 0.51 W)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140801/discussion-on-question-by-gk-raj-how-to-turn-on-off-a-5v-10a-relay-from-5v-0-2).

Answer (score 2):

The relay coil requires 72mA (360mW/5). That's easily accomplished with a BJT such as 2N4401.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6LPz7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You could also use a small MOSFET such as AO3400 (SOT-23 package).

IRFZ is inappropriate because it takes too much drive voltage, and the TIP122 Darlington is inappropriate because it drops too much voltage.